# Javascript while loop inside .after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

Is it possible to write a while loop inside a .after() for example

```
$(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="description"><select name="description">' + while(x<2){ + '<option>' + variable + '</option> '+ x++; } + '</select></td></tr>');
```

Comment: No.  It looks like you might want to build the string outside of the `.after()` and then pass in the built string.

Comment: Maybe you caught the errors in my answer already, but I updated it to add the missing `}` and also to make sure that "x" gets incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like that, but you could always use a function:

```
$(".item-row:last").after(function() {
  var markup = '<tr class="item-row"><td class="description"><select name="description">';
  while (x < 2) {
    markup += '<option>' + variable + '</option>';
    x++;
  }
  markup += '</select></td></tr>';
  return markup;
}());
```

Note that the function in the ".after()" argument list is *called*, so ".after()" is passed the *result* of calling that anonymous function.